# Can you add two alarm action references to the same AWS CloudWatch Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have some cloudwatch alarms configured in json and yml files.

Can more than one reference be added to AlarmActions like so?

Yml

```
 AlarmActions:
    - Ref: SNSTopicEmail
    - Ref: SNSTopicEmail1
```

JSON

```
"AlarmActions": [
    {
        "Ref": "SNSTopicEmail"
    },
    {
        "Ref": "SNSTopicEmail1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try and see what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you use CloudFormation to created those alarms. According to the [CloudFormation Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-alarmactions) is it possible to  configure up to 5 alarm actions on an `AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm`